# Two Pandas dataframes, how to interpolate row-wise using scipy

Tags: pandas, scipy, interpolation

How can I use scipy interpolate on two dataframes, interpolating row-rise?

For example, if I have:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6], "b": [3.2, 4.1, 1.1, 2.8]})
dfy = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0.8, 0.2, 1.1, 0.1], "b": [0.5, 1.3, 1.3, 2.8]})
display(dfx)
display(dfy)
```

[image]

And say I want to interpolate for y(x=0.5), how can I get the results into an array that I can put in a new dataframe?

Expected result is: `[0.761290323 0.284615385 1.1 -0.022727273]`

For example, for first row, you can see the expected value is 0.761290323:

```
x = [0.1, 3.2] # from dfx, row 0
y = [0.8,0.5] # from dfy, row 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)

f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
out = f(0.5)
print(out)
```

[image]

I tried the following but received `ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.`

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(dfx, dfy)
out = np.exp(f(0.5))
print(out)
```

Comment: What do you mean interpolate row-wise? What is `x` here?

Comment: @QuangHoang OP updated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for linear interpolation, you can do:

```
def interpolate(val, dfx, dfy):
    t = (dfx['b'] - val) / (dfx['b'] - dfx['a'])
    return dfy['a'] * t + dfy['b'] * (1-t)

interpolate(0.5, dfx, dfy)
```

Output:

```
0    0.885714
1    0.284615
2    1.100000
3   -0.022727
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I used linear interpolation for simplicity, I will use spline in reality, which is why I specified scipy module